# Can a mft_reference correspond to two different files at different time?

Tags: ntfs, ntfs-mft

I am working on parsing USN Journal files now, and what I know is that in USN Journal log entry, there is a **mft_reference** field, it references the corresponding **FileRecord** in MFT table.
After a period of time, the USN Journal files may accumulate quite lot of file change records, such as *file adding*, *file modifying*, *file deleting*.
If I just get a mft_reference number(64 bits integer) `mft_refer_1` at the very beginning of the USN Journal file, and get another mft_reference number `mft_refer_2` at the end of the USN Journal file, and they are equal in value, `mft_refer_1 == mft_refer_2` Can I say the two journal records are specifying the same file?
What I am not quite sure is if an later added **FileRecord** will replace the position of a former deleted **FileRecord**.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470124(v=vs.85).aspx), I think I already have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out this by experimenting with "fsutil usn" tools;

First we should know how mft_refer is composed: 
**0xAAAABBBBBBBBBBBB**, where AAAA stands for update number, and BBBBBBBBBBBB stands for File Record index into MFT table.

First I create a text document named by "**daniel.txt**", and find out its mft_refer is **0x00050000000c6c3f**,

and then I delete it to Recycle Bin, its name is changed to something like "**$R2QW90X.txt**", but its mft_refer is still **0x00050000000c6c3f**,

I delete it thoroughtly from Recycle Bin, and create another document also named as "**daniel.txt**", now the new document's mft_refer is **0x00040000000c6c48**,

and then I create several other temporary files, one of these files occupies the **0x00000000000c6c3f**-th file record with an updated mft_refer **0x00060000000c6c3f**.

So my coclusion is the file record space is very precious in MFT, if a previous file has been thoroughtly deleted, then the file record space will be reclaimed for a new created file, but will update the "update number" field in mft_refer.

For the detailed experiment process, see [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/long123king/p/3540903.html)